# Get custom field from Wordpress term

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, taxonomy

I've made a simple loop over a custom taxonomy 'product_category':

```
$args = array('hide_empty' => false, 'orderby' => 'term_group', 'parent' => false);
$terms = get_terms('product_categorie', $args);

foreach ($terms as $term) {
    echo "<a href=''>".$term->name."</a>";
}
```

I've added a custom field 'webshop_url' to the taxonomy. I've tried multiple solutions to print that custom field in my loop, but without luck.

I've tried these things in my foreach loop:

```
echo get_field('webshop_url', 'product_categorie', $term->term_id);

echo get_field('webshop_url', $term->term_id);
```

It doesn't print anything.

I know it's possible to use `get_queried_object()` on the taxonomy page itself. But that doesn't work either in that loop.

Comment: You need to prefix the term ID accordingly, see https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/#examples, section “Get a value from different objects”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass term OBJECT

```
echo get_field('webshop_url', $term);
```

Answer (score 0):

May you try like this:

[ACF Document](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/)

```
$args = array('hide_empty' => false, 'orderby' => 'term_group', 'parent' => false);
$terms = get_terms('product_categorie', $args);

foreach( $terms as $term ) {
    $webshop_url = get_field('webshop_url', 'product_categorie'.'_'.$term->term_id);
    var_dump($webshop_url);
}
```

Comment: Nope, still no result. 
This worked: echo get_field('webshop_url', $term);

Comment: @Dennis that's logic working for me. and i have also used in many projects. thanks